# php how to ensure that parent class gets constructed

Tags: php, class, parent, extend, construction

What is the best way to ensure that parent class allways gets constructed, since we can easily override constructors without having to call them at all.

Also: is this bad practice?

```
abstract class A
{
 // make it final to ensure parent constructor is allways used
 final function __construct($param1)
 {
  // do essencial stuff here with $param1
  // pass construction with remaining args to child
  call_user_func_array(array($this,'init'),array_slice(func_get_args(),1));
 }
 abstract function init();
}

class B extends A
{
 function init($param2)
 {
  // effectively extends parent constructor, no?
 }
}

$obj = new B("p1","p2");
```

Comment: that will work.  What are your reservations?

Comment: Why *must* the parent constructor be called, and why is it so important that you cannot reply on those who are extending your class to properly call your constructor? It smells like a design flaw to me. Please explain what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: @Sander: I have a set of development classes whose constructors take too many arguments and do a lot essencial initializations. Client code must be able to extend these classes easily without overriding their constructors. If they (Client) need their child classes to do anything on construction as well, they simply add code to the init method or else leave it blank.

Comment: @fabio: See [this article](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/introduce-parameter-object) on Parameter Objects to reduce the number of arguments to your methods/constructors...

Comment: @fabio: Along with ircmaxell's suggestion, also have a look at [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). That may help cut down on the initialisation in your constructors and even help make your classes simpler.

Answer (score 2):

You can explicitly call parent's constructor by calling:

```
parent::__construct(<params>);
```

Also as far as I know, constructors should be `public`.

Comment: Constructors can be public, but they don't have to be.  There are a fair number of use-cases for having non-public constructors (factory methods, forcing a child class to declare a public constructor, etc)...

Comment: @ircmaxell: do you also include protected constructors when you say "non-public" constructors? Would there be an use-case for such a thing?

Comment: @fabio: Of course. Anywhere where you have a private constructor but want to give the option to extend. Factory methods and frameworks are an excellent example. Frameworks are meant to be extended. They shouldn't have any private methods.

Comment: Another example of a situation where one could imagine making a protected (or even a private, if you don't need to inherit) constructor is when implementing a singleton pattern.